# How to prevent Texmaker to missunderstand Alt+Tab as auto completion command when it is meant for swiching windows

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

When I compile a pdf document in texmaker, I often press Alt+Tab to swich to the external pdf viewer.

If at that point the cursor in texmaker is by coincidence at a position where texmaker can make an auto-completion, pressing Alt will show the options for auto completion, pressing Tab will highlight the first option and releasing both will select the first option.

This can be very anoying when the cursor is in the middle of a complicated formular. Is there a way to prevent texmaker to missunderstand the Alt-Tab command without swiching off auto-completion completely? I am using Texmaker 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.4 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

TexMaker is hard-coded to use typable keys to activate auto-completion, e.g., any character key including {}[](), etc.. However, there is a bug, it took ALT key as one of typable keys which is wrong.

For now, the only work-around is to turn off auto-completion. It's in Options-> Configure TexMaker->Shortcuts.

Comment: It's actually in: Options-> Configure TexMaker->Editor, and you have to untick "completion"